# Add autoplay to this jQuery Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, autoplay

I've created a carousel using jQuery and I would like to add auto-play functionality to it.

Here's my existing JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#button a').click(function(){
        var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-705*(parseInt(integer)-1)})
        $('#button a').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
                $(this).addClass('active')}
        });
    });
});​
```

And here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gy7LE/1/).

**Question:** I have no idea where to start with auto-play. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/gy7LE/13/

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    $('#button a').click(function(){
        var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
        $('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-705*(parseInt(integer)-1)})
        $('#button a').each(function(){
            $(this).removeClass('active');
            if($(this).hasClass('button'+integer)){
                $(this).addClass('active')}
        });
    });
        setInterval ( function(){Next();}, 1000 );
    });

    function Next(){
        var _next = false;
        $('#button a').each(function(){
            if(_next){
                $(this).addClass('active');
                _next = false;
            }
            else if($(this).hasClass('active')){
                _next = true;
                $(this).removeClass('active')
            }

        });  
        if(_next)
            $("#button a:eq(0)").addClass("active");

       var activeIndex = parseInt($(".active").attr("rel"));
       $('#myslide .cover').animate({left:-705*(parseInt(activeIndex))});      
    }
​
```

Comment: I don't see the autoplay working? It starts at 2, and then, nothing ?

Comment: thanks for your help!! But one thing, when you actually click on the button, the autoplay is all messed up. James Hill's code doesnt do that.

Comment: if you wanna stop the auto-play just clear the interval. like here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gy7LE/13/)

Comment: Thanks. One more thing, the first time you run it, it starts with the second div, instead of the 1st one.

Comment: i update it. just delete de Next(); inside $(document).ready()

Answer (score 1):

This will work. See comments in code:

```
var slideInterval = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#button a').click(function() {
        //Clear slide interval to allow overriding of auto slide
        if (slideInterval !== null) clearInterval(slideInterval);

        var integer = $(this).attr('rel');
        DoSlide(integer);
    });

    //Begin auto slide
    slideInterval = setInterval(DoSlide , 2000);
});

function DoSlide(integer) {
    integer = integer || parseInt($('.active').attr('rel')) + 1;

    // Reset auto slide
    if (integer == 5) integer = 1;

    $('#myslide .cover').animate({
        left: -705 * (parseInt(integer) - 1)
    });

    $('.active').removeClass('active');    
    $('a[rel="' + integer + '"]').addClass('active');
}​
```

Here's [a working fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/sNqrf/).

Comment: I think there is a problem the second time it plays. So it goes from 1,2,3,4 then 1, and then, not working anymore..?

Comment: @Lelly, just posted a comment in your original question. I forgot to update the code/fiddle to the latest version. The bug is gone - try now.

Comment: this is poor solution. It have contant indexes.

Comment: @Yorgo, can you elaborate? Also, could you provide a solution that's not quite as poor as mine?

Comment: @JamesHill you are using index to cycle the auto-play in here : `if (integer == 5) integer = 1;` I give answer. You can check that

Comment: @Lelly, quick update - I removed the need for the `.each()` iteration at the end of `DoSlide`. It was unnecessary.

Comment: ok thanks, just noticed, I there seems to be a problem with your Fiddle in Firefox ? The first time it runs, something wierd happens, do you see that as well?  Im using FF 11.0

Answer (score 1):

A more elegant solution

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.carousel-control.right').trigger('click');
    $('.carousel-inner').trigger('mouseenter');
    $('.carousel-inner').trigger('mouseleave');
  }, 3000); //set this time to what ever time you want it to take to start scrolling this is separate for the interval you set for the carousel though you can set it to be the same BooStrap default is 4000
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try [this plugin](https://github.com/ehudg/scrapercarousel), it looks for images for you and creates auto carousel.