# How to Make My Waterwheel Carousel Auto Play?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this script and I want to add an auto play mod. This is the start:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var carousel = $("#carousel").waterwheelCarousel({
      flankingItems: 3,
      movingToCenter: function ($item) {
        $('#callback-output').prepend('movingToCenter: ' + $item.attr('id') + '<br/>');
      },
      movedToCenter: function ($item) {
        $('#callback-output').prepend('movedToCenter: ' + $item.attr('id') + '<br/>');
      },
      movingFromCenter: function ($item) {
        $('#callback-output').prepend('movingFromCenter: ' + $item.attr('id') + '<br/>');
      },
      movedFromCenter: function ($item) {
        $('#callback-output').prepend('movedFromCenter: ' + $item.attr('id') + '<br/>');
      },
      clickedCenter: function ($item) {
        $('#callback-output').prepend('clickedCenter: ' + $item.attr('id') + '<br/>');
      }
    });
```

Here are the navigation buttons:

```
    $('#prev').bind('click', function () {
      carousel.prev();
      return false
    });

    $('#next').bind('click', function () {
      carousel.next();
      return false;
    });

    $('#reload').bind('click', function () {
      newOptions = eval("(" + $('#newoptions').val() + ")");
      carousel.reload(newOptions);
      return false;
    });

  });
```

Can anyone please help me to do that?

And here is my `css` code:

```
body {
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size:12px;
    background:#ededed;
}
.example-desc {
    margin:3px 0;
    padding:5px;
}

#carousel {
    width:960px;

    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Hide images until carousel can handle them, otherwise it's not as obvious items can be clicked:

```
#carousel img {
    visibility:hidden; 
    cursor:pointer;
}

.split-left {
    width:450px;
    float:left;
}
.split-right {
    width:400px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#callback-output {
    height:250px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
textarea#newoptions {
    width:430px;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10142662/add-autoplay-to-this-jquery-carousel

Answer (score 0):

Read [the documentation](http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-waterwheel-carousel/options).

Add `autoPlay: 5000,` (where 5000 is the number of milliseconds between changes) to the options.